# Entry list field get duplicated entries from specific section

Tags: entries, saveentry

I have some weird behavior when I have an entry list field (in a super table, but I get the same behavior from the native entry list field type).

When I select an entry from a certain section, it will populate 2(!) entries in that list, which point to the same entry after save. It looks correct, after I selected the entry, but as soon as I save the entry which contain the list, it gets duplicated?

Before saving:
[image]

After Save:
[image]

It only affects a single, specific section, entries from any other section is fine.

Where to even start trouble-shooting?

Comment: Is the section you are choosing entries **from** (sidlista) a structure? If so, run `./craft utils/repair/section-structure sectionHandle` replacing `sectionHandle` with the handle of the section you are choosing the entries **from**.

Comment: @Oli Yes, it is a structure. I ran the suggested command but the same issue is sitll there.

Comment: Can you write in to `support@craftcms.com` and send your `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and a database backup. We'll help you from there.